# /etc/modules not working as expected

Tags: drivers, kernel, 15.10, automatic

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 desktop on my laptop.

When I execute:

```
$ sudo modprobe b43
```

module b43 is loaded and my wifi interface starts working, I can connect to my SSID home network fine.

Now I want to load b43 module automatically after booting my Ubuntu system. To do that, I added "b43" to /etc/modules,

```
$ cat /etc/modules
b43
```

and rebooted Ubuntu. But after rebooting, b43 module is not shown on lsmod:

```
$ lsmod | grep b43
[none]
```

What should be done to get this working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I already fixed this issue. Module b43 was blacklisted into this file:

$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf
blacklist b43

After commenting that blacklist line, adding '#' as first char, I rebooted my laptop and the module b43 was loaded as expected.

It works like a charm! :)